# React-native-fcm not pushing notifications for closed app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, android-manifest, firebase-cloud-messaging

My App was getting notification only when app is open and in background. but i require notifications should reach even app is closed. How could i do this in reactnative using react-native-fcm?

My code was below please refer to it

```
FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notif=>console.log(notif));
            FCM.requestPermissions(); // for iOS
            FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
                console.log(token)
                // store fcm token in your server
            });
            this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
                // there are two parts of notif. notif.notification contains the notification payload, notif.data contains data payload
                if(notif.local_notification){
                  //this is a local notification
                  return;
                }
                if(notif.opened_from_tray){
                  //app is open/resumed because user clicked banner
                  console.log('clicked');

                  return;
                }
                this.showLocalNotification(notif);

            });
            this.refreshTokenListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.RefreshToken, (token) => {
                console.log(token)
                // fcm token may not be available on first load, catch it here
            });

      showLocalNotification(notif) {
          FCM.presentLocalNotification({
            title: notif.title,
            body: notif.body,
            priority: "high",
            click_action: notif.click_action,
            show_in_foreground: true,
            local: true
          });
      }
```

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <receiver android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.FIRLocalMessagingPublisher"/>
      <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.FIRSystemBootEventReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
          <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

      <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.MessagingService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </service>

      <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.InstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </service>

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="fcm.ACTION.HELLO" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXXXXX"/>
    </application>
```

Comment: Have you considered using `data`-*only* payload messages?

Comment: I am sending both data and notifications. I am new to this. i am just using react-native-fcm for my requirment.

Comment: Sorry. I got confused. I thought you preferred to handle the messages on your own when the app is in foreground/background. It's the behavior of Android that when sending a payload with both `data` and `notification`, the Notification Tray would handle the payload. Are you not seeing any notifications at all? Have you tested this on multiple devices?

Comment: I am able to see the notifications on all devices but only if the app is open or in background. i require even while app is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is how you are pushing your notification.
The FCM will recognise and popup only notifications which contains the attribute "notification".

If you need the command

> this.showLocalNotification(notif);

to show your notification it means your are managing notifications locally, hence, your closed app won't manage it.

As a result, please check how you are sending your notification to the cloud and be sure the event "FCMEvent.Notification" is triggered only if you dont have a "notification" attribute.

Ex:

```
noteA = {notification: {title: "Notification Title", body:"Notification body"}, data: {optional: "content"}};
noteB = {title: "Notification Title", body:"Notification body"}, data: {optional: "content"}};
```

Result:

noteA: Should popup a notification without triggering FCMEvent.Notification

noteB: Should trigger FCMEvent.Notification and if this.showLocalNotification(notif) is invoked a local notification will be shown.